# fish shell login commands keep running on screen or tmux session after login

Tags: bash, shell, unix, centos7, fish

I've just switched to [fish-shell](https://fishshell.com/)

And I've used the instructions of  [How do I run a command every login? What's fish's equivalent to .bashrc?](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-login-cmd)

Which means I've moved the commands which i prefer to run upon login from `.bashrc` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

But right now the commands keep running if i open `screen` or `tmux` session ! but before while i were using the default shell that's was never happens (meant that the commands were only run during the login and never re-run in `screen` session)

How to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for the `TERM` environmental variable to see if your shell is running in such a session. Both `screen` and `tmux` by default set it to 'screen'.

```
if not string match --quiet -e $TERM 'screen'
    <your startup scripts>
end
```

Note that other useful indicators are whether a shell is *interactive* or a *login shell*. You can use `status --is-interactive` and `status --is-login` to check for these two states.

In your specific case, a check for *login shell* might be what you are looking for:

```
if status --is-login
    <your startup scripts>
end
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell for an explanation.

Comment: thanks a lot. both solutions works fine. but i used the first one since tmux is already a login shell. right now if open `tmux` or `screen` session, the word of `screen` is usually appear. can i remove it ? thanks again, sorry I'm just not familiar with bash code at all.